# Groovy Python node cannot find move_base_msgs module

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, move-base-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My setup: Latest Groovy debs on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

I have a simple Python node in a catkin package that needs to import MoveBaseAction and MoveBaseGoal from move_base_msgs.  My import line looks like this:

```
from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal
```

which worked fine in Fuerte.  My package.xml file includes the line:

```
<run_depend>move_base_msgs</run_depend>
```

And my Groovy debian installation has the move_base_msgs package installed:

```
$ rospack find move_base_msgs
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation/move_base_msgs
```

But when I try to run the node I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/patrick/Dropbox/Robotics/ros/catkin_ws/src/rbx2/rbx2_tasks/nodes/nav_tasks.py", line 35, in <module>
    from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal
ImportError: No module named move_base_msgs.msg
```

Other message imports work fine; for example, I can import the Odometry message type from nav_msgs.msg using:

```
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
```

with the following line in my package.xml file:

```
  <run_depend>nav_msgs</run_depend>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58573/groovy-python-node-cannot-find-move_base_msgs-module/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tadhg Fitzgerald](https://answers.ros.org/users/4009/tadhg-fitzgerald/) on 2013-03-19**:
Sorry I can't help. ROS by example is a great book though, just wanted to say thanks, helped a lot with my final year project:)

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-03-19**:
Thanks @Tadhg Fitzgerald :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin packages can only depend on catkin packages, and move_base_msgs has yet to be catkinized.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-03-19**:
Thanks @fergs.  Guess I'll wait until Hydro to do any more playing with catkin...

**Comment by [Sj_Nath](https://answers.ros.org/users/117255/sj_nath/) on 2022-10-27**:
I am getting the same issue. Can you share the link for catkinized move_base_msgs.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to wait for the Hydro version, it's out already!  You just need to get it.

Clone the [github repo](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation) (git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git) and copy the move_base_msgs folder into a catkin workspace on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.  You can delete the rest of the repo as you don't need it.  (If you need to make a catkin workspace then you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace))

Now you can `catkin_make` from the root of the workspace and Python will be able to `import move_base_msgs` happily.

---

Originally posted by [RobAnswers](https://answers.ros.org/users/5977/robanswers/) with karma: 11 on 2013-08-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sj_Nath](https://answers.ros.org/users/117255/sj_nath/) on 2022-10-27**:
I have tried it. Even **rosmsg package my_package** lists the messages. **rosmsg show MoveBaseAction** shows the whole info. Still It is not working.